# Jquery / Javascript Solution for URL matches Href then add a Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, href

So, i got a basic page where i need to highlight where my user is. Got a Nav with ul > li > a

my ideia is to get the URL of the current page, and match with one specific href of one "a".

The structure :

```
   <header>

<a href="#" id="toggle-nav"><span class="trigger"></span></a>

<nav>
    <ul id="nav-top">
        <li><a href="../Index/Index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="#">Aluno</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="../Index/areadoaluno.html" title="Area do Aluno">Area Do Aluno</a></li>
                <li><a>sub-item</a></li>
                <li><a>sub-item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Json</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="Json.html" title="Teste Json">Json Teste</a></li>
                <li><a>sub-item</a></li>
                <li><a>sub-item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

and the jquery with javascript (Its ok to mix this two guys ? ):

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var i;
var location = "";

for(i = 0; i < url.length; i++)
    {
        location += url[i];     
    }


    $('#nav-top a').each(function(){

    var href = $(this).attr('href'); 

        if( location.indexOf(href) > -1 ) 

        {
            alert("Yes!");

        } 

    });
});
```

Im studing Jquery and jscript yet, so im kind of new, im working with a solution that can find and match one part of my url with an specific href, idependent of the size of the url, and for where i go.

Comment: There are already dozens of answers regarding on "How to mark active a current link" here on StackOverflow - Goog is your friend.

Comment: Which `href` are you trying to match? That would enable us to reproduce the error/create a jsfiddle

Comment: would be the "href" of the current page, example .. im at Home , so the home button gain an "active" class.

So , he check the URL if has something that apears on one of the a hrefs, he get that one a and set a active class. 

@RokoC.Buljan -> Already check the stack for answers, not finding something that can help me.  This one solution that i post i get through those answers by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejjw1g2j/)

I think you could just do as is shown. No need to loop through `url` and no need for extra variable `location`.

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');

$('#nav-top a').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href'); 
    if (url.indexOf(href) > -1) {
        alert("Yes!");
    } 
});
```

And yes, it's perfectly okay to mix jQuery and JS. jQuery is a JS library so that's what it's made for

Comment: Indeed works on fiddle, but here its not working, something im missing ... my location of tests its here at the cpu (file:///C:/Users/....) ... this could have something to do with the solution its not working ?

Comment: nope, not a single one.

It seems just that when he matches the href and url he doesnt return a "equal", cause my else works.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to match on this: `if (url === href)` or `if (url.indexOf(href) > -1)`? The former evaluates to true if the **whole** of `url` equals `href`. The latter returns true if `href` is only in **part** /all of `url`

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation im doing this if (url.indexOf(href) > -1) .. i need to match just one part of the url.

Comment: Do you have an `else` clause and does it enter that? If so, check that the url and href is what you expect them to be by logging them to the console

Comment: here is my href <a href="../Index/Index.html" ...  maybe for how it´s that is not working ?

Comment: And what is the url you are at when you load this page?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/renat/Desktop/Htmls-css-teste-estudos/Ambiente_Interno_DevDesg/LIntelligence_Ludus/Index/Index.html

Comment: Ah yes that'll be why!! In href, you have '..' which will obviously not be present in your url so the `if` condition will always evaluate to false. Bets idea is to omit that '..' out of the href. You can do this using `.slice()`

Comment: makes sense!! i would have something like "    var href = $(this).attr('href').slice('..')" ?